# Can I reload monitors.xml without restarting LightDM?

Tags: bash, multiple-monitors, lightdm

I was writing myself a short [script](http://ubuntuone.com/5wMmEyz3KJDVb5Bkg7JD6y) to turn off my laptops monitor in order to only use the bigger external monitor, as I don't always want to use Unity GUI. But after turning the laptop monitor back on with the same script the configurations were all wrong, so I was wondering if there is a way to reload `monitors.xml` (from the ./config) where all the configurations are stored without restarting whole `lightdm`? I did this in the current script, and not only killed it all my programs but also did I get an error regarding my keyboard input.

About the setting: My left, smaller monitor is my primary and the right one the secondary. But if `monitor.xml` is not reloaded both are primary monitors.

Is it probably necessary to restart lightdm? If so, how can I do that in a as secure as possible way without killing all processes (if possible of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the exact mechanism to reload monitors.xml, but I do know that file is a GNOME thing.  So maybe killing and restarting gnome-settings-daemon would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, i am going to try that as soon as i can. But killing gnome-settings does sound like it would bring a number other problems with it. I'll report when i tried it

Comment: You should only lose theming and such for a few moments while gnome-session restarts it.  I hope, but cannot confirm that it will also reset your monitor setup when it comes back.

Comment: I tried it, and it partially worked, but funnily `gnome-settings-daemon` was not running on startup (but it loaded monitors.xml anyway on startup). After that I could not reload it with `killall` or `kill` because it neither found the name nor did the PID show up in `top`.

Comment: I found a better solution for my problem for which I will post an answer, but as your question actually answers the given question I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 4):

I found a very simple way to solve the problem:

It is possible to give `xrandr` the configurations for the monitor as additional options. In my case it were the following:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto --mode 1366x768 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --primary
xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --mode 1680x1050 --pos 1366x0 --rotate normal
```

with `LVDS1` being the laptops monitor and `VGA1` the external monitor. (can be inqueried with `xrandr -q`).

This way it is not necessary to reload `monitors.xml` or restart `lightdm` and one can even specify different configurations in one scirpt.

Comment: If you run `arandr` and go to `Layout->Save As`, it will write this script for you.